# Timed Pagination or Scrolling in Django

Tags: javascript, django, time, pagination

I have a very simple Django webapp that tracks job status in a shop.  It works fine, but I'd like to add in a feature that automatically scrolls or changes pages, whichever is easier, every 30 seconds so that if there are more jobs than fit on one screen, it shows all the jobs on a time interval.  Is anyone aware of a method to do this with Django or javascript?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a relatively simple solution for this after looking around the web.  Thought it might be helpful for someone down the line.

I used a little javascript script:

```
<script>

setInterval(function(){ location.reload() }, 600000);

$(document).ready(function scroll(){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#start').offset().top }, 40000).delay(5000),
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#stop').offset().top }, 40000), scroll();
})
scroll();
</script>
```

I just put in the head html page, but you could load it in the static folder as well.  I just added two objects on the page, one at the top called 'start' and one called 'stop', i.e. I put an image at the top as follows:

```
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" id="start">
```

It is simple but it works very well and just scrolls up and down all day.